# Pulling from private repo in kubernetes fails with "The Secret "docker-credentials" is invalid: data[.dockerconfigjson]: Required value"

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am trying to pull images from my docker-hub repo. I followed the documentation found here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/

However, after typing in the command:

> kubectl create secret generic docker-credentials --from-file=/my/local/path/to/.docker/config.json --type=kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson

I get the following error:

> The Secret "docker-credentials" is invalid: data[.dockerconfigjson]:
> Required value

I tried deleting the config.json and re-logging in but with no change in behaviour.

docker version prints:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.5
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.12
 Git commit:        633a0ea838
 Built:             Wed Nov 13 07:29:52 2019
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.5
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.12.12
  Git commit:       633a0ea838
  Built:            Wed Nov 13 07:28:22 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.2.10
  GitCommit:        b34a5c8af56e510852c35414db4c1f4fa6172339
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc8+dev
  GitCommit:        3e425f80a8c931f88e6d94a8c831b9d5aa481657
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```

kubectl version prints:

```
Client Version: version.Info{
  Major:"1",
  Minor:"17",
  GitVersion:"v1.17.2",
  GitCommit:"59603c6e503c87169aea6106f57b9f242f64df89",
  GitTreeState:"clean",
  BuildDate:"2020-01-18T23:30:10Z",
  GoVersion:"go1.13.5",
  Compiler:"gc",
  Platform:"linux/amd64"
}
Server Version: version.Info{
  Major:"1",
  Minor:"15",
  GitVersion:"v1.15.2",
  GitCommit:"f6278300bebbb750328ac16ee6dd3aa7d3549568",
  GitTreeState:"clean",
  BuildDate:"2019-08-05T09:15:22Z",
  GoVersion:"go1.12.5",
  Compiler:"gc",
  Platform:"linux/amd64"
}
```

the config.json looks like this:

```
{
    "auths": {
        "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
            "auth": "secret-stuff"
        }
    },
    "HttpHeaders": {
        "User-Agent": "Docker-Client/19.03.5 (linux)"
    }
}
```

For the moment I can enter the credentials manually but I'd like to understand what's going wrong.

Comment: It seems odd that this was closed, after a year, with 3 answers, even though there are lots of k8s and docker questions on SO that somehow don't qualify as pro networking or ops questions. As a DevOps guy I run into this problem in my dev environment all the time when using private corporate repos on docker hub (for development).

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same issue with `kubectl create secret generic --type=kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson` ("*The Secret "xxx" is invalid: data[.dockerconfigjson]: Required value*") and it was because of a mistake in the command line, which I think Marcus's command has too.

I had:

`--from-file=/run/user/xxxx/containers/auth.json`

It was supposed to be:

`--from-file=.dockerconfigjson=/run/user/xxxx/containers/auth.json`

I mis-interpreted the --from-file option as taking a file path, but it takes a key=value, which I guess in this case is supposed to be the key ".dockerconfigjson".

The answer by Crou hints at --from-file as the culprit, but I thought I would add an answer to spell out what's missing.  (And I think the point about the file `type` being missing was misleading, because the --type option is there in the command, that's why I skipped over that answer originally when looking at this question for help.)

Note that I got a hint of what was wrong by running kubectl in verbose mode (--v=N, see https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#kubectl-output-verbosity-and-debugging), which showed kubectl telling the API server the structure of the Secret resource, and the structure didn't say ".dockerconfigjson" like I expected from the Secret YAML examples in the Kubernetes docs.

Answer (score 1):

While creating the `secret` you did not specified the `Type`  of a file you will be reading from so `kubectl` did not read the file properly.

List of types is as follows:

```
SecretTypeOpaque SecretType = "Opaque"
[...]
SecretTypeServiceAccountToken SecretType = "kubernetes.io/service-account-token"
[...]
SecretTypeDockercfg SecretType = "kubernetes.io/dockercfg"
[...]
SecretTypeDockerConfigJSON SecretType = "kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson"
[...]
SecretTypeBasicAuth SecretType = "kubernetes.io/basic-auth"
[...]
SecretTypeSSHAuth SecretType = "kubernetes.io/ssh-auth"
[...]
SecretTypeTLS SecretType = "kubernetes.io/tls"
[...]
SecretTypeBootstrapToken SecretType = "bootstrap.kubernetes.io/token"
```

which you can find at Kubernetes GitHub [kubernetes/pkg/apis/core/types.go](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/apis/core/types.go#L4760-L4845)

The correct command in your case would be 
`kubectl create secret generic docker-credentials --from-file=.dockerconfigjson=path/to/.docker/config.json --type=kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson`

Please give attention into `--from-file=.dockerconfigjson=path/to/.docker/config.json`, you should be editing only `path/to/.docker/config.json`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't run the docker login command with docker private repository, hence the config.json file doesn't have the authentication informations. You can refer the below sample file.

Example:

```
  {
    "auths": {

     "https://dockerhub.xxxxx.com": {
        "auth": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "email": "xxxxx@xxxxx.com"
     }
   },
   "HttpHeaders": {
      "User-Agent": "Docker-Client/18.06.1-ce (linux)"
   }
 }
```